# How do I disable dragging out of my Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a Cocoa Mac app that uses drag and drop within the app. I want to disable dragging things like images from my app to other apps, like the Finder. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to disable *features*?

Comment: I got a similar situation. I want to drag `NSWindow`s within the application and the drag data is a `NSString`, so I can parse it and know what `NSWindow` was dragged. Outside my application, the dragged string has no meaning besides exposing internal information.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a genuine reason why you must prevent the images from being dragged outside the app, then you should [declare your own UTI](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW2) in your Info.plist that you can use as the drag type for internal-only drags.

You then specify your custom UTI when declaring your pasteboard types. For example, in your view that supports dragging:

```
//the UTI string should match the one in your Info.plist
static NSString* kYourCustomUTIType = @"com.yourCompany.internalDragType";

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSSize dragOffset = NSZeroSize;
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];

    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:kYourCustomUTIType] owner:self];
    [pboard setData:[[self image] TIFFRepresentation] forType:kYourCustomUTIType];

    [self dragImage:[self image] at:[self imageLocation] offset:dragOffset
        event:theEvent pasteboard:pboard source:self slideBack:YES];

    return;
}
```

Of course, you'd need to make sure that your dragging destination understands your internal drag type as well.

In general, however, unless you have a real reason why the images should not be dragged outside the app then you should just allow the default behaviour. Mac users expect drag and drop to "just work" and by breaking it you are making your app stand out, and not in a good way.